# Creating and saving a model object with a calculated m2m field Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

New to Django, I don't know if it's still worth it. I'm currently trying to save a model form with a many-to-many field that should be set randomly according to other fields(category, subcategory, number) in the same form. how do I get it to work?

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    categ=models.ManyToManyField(Category,blank=False)
    sscateg = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategory,blank = True,null= True)
    question = models.ManyToManyField (Question,related_name='questionsEx',blank=False) 
    nbquestion = models.IntegerField()
    def save(self, *args, **Kwargs):
        super(Exam, self).save(*args,**Kwargs,commit=False)
        if self.pk:
                          qs=Question.objects.filter(category=self.categ).filter(sscateg=self.sscateg).values_list('id',flat =True)
            questions = random.sample(qs,self.nbquestion)
            for quest in questions:
                self.question.add(quest)
        super(Exam, self).save(*args,**Kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ExamForm(forms.ModelForm):
   
    nbquestion = forms.IntegerField(required = False)
    categ=forms.ModelChoiceField(Category.objects.all(),
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required = False)
    sscateg=forms.ModelChoiceField(SsCategory.objects.all(),
                  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=False)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = forms.ModelForm.save(self, False)
        self.save_m2m()
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class ExCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url  = 'login'
    template_name = 'MakeEx.html'
    model = Exam
    form_class = ExamForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Exams')
    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return super(ExCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not save an m2m before saving the instance, likely it is not necessary either, and probably not a good idea to do this in the `save` method.

You should do this probably in the form, so we work with a simple model:

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    categ = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    sscateg = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategory, blank=True, null=True)
    question = models.ManyToManyField(
        Question, related_name='questionsEx', blank=False
    )
    nbquestion = models.IntegerField()

    # no save method
```

and then we add the questions in the form *after* saving the many-to-many fields:

```
class ExamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    nbquestion = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    categ = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        Category.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=False,
    )
    sscateg = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        SsCategory.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = ('categ', 'sscateg', 'nbquestion')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        adding = self.instance._state.adding
        # first add
        instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if adding:
            instance.question.add(
                *Question.objects.filter(category__exam=instance, sscateg__exam=instance)
                .values_list('id', flat=True)
                .order_by('?').distinct()[: self.nbquestion]
            )
        return instance
```

the `CreateView` is a simple view:

```
class ExCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    template_name = 'MakeEx.html'
    model = Exam
    form_class = ExamForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Exams')
    # no form_valid
```

---

> **Note**: You do not have to store the number of items of a `ManyToManyField` in another field. You can use [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) when you need to determine this by the database. Storing this explicitly in a field is a form of *data duplication*, and it turns out that keeping these in sync is harder than what one might expect.

Comment: Tried it but did not save the object. I made number of items stored explicitly because it should be chosen by the user.

Comment: @Dev23: what do you mean with it did not save *the* object? The `Exam` object or the questions? The form should at least save the `Exam`.

Comment: The exam object . It should populate Exam question field randomly from existing question objects.

Comment: @Dev23: well that is normally done with `if adding:` does the code reaches that point (add a `print` statement).

Comment: No it does not reach it.

Comment: @Dev23: does it actually call the `.save()` method of the form. If not, the view should trigger the save method of the form.

Comment: no it does not call it. how can the view trigger it

Comment: @Dev23: it will, if you just omit the `form_valid` call, the `CreateView` is normally saving the form in the `form_valid` method. But the fact that that does not happen either means the form was invalid, or there was no POST request to trigger creating an object in the first place.

Comment: i did omit the 'form_valid' . I think the problem is probably with the m2m field.

Comment: @Dev23: did you exclude the `question` in the `fields` of the `ExamForm`?

Comment: @Dev23: see the edit for the `Meta` that should be used, omitting the `question` field.